# How can I edit a form created by using Form.io in MVC

Tags: forms, formio

I created form using *Form.io* in MVC. Now I want to edit the created form how can I do that. I have HTML of the created form. If someone kindly assist me in it. I am new to *Form.io*. And I really need to edit form my code is posted below.

```
   Formio.builder(document.getElementById('builder'), {}, {
    builder: {
        basic: false
        customBasic: {
            title: 'Basic Components',
            default: true,
            weight: 0,
            components: {
                textfield: true,
                textarea: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
        layout: {
            components: {
                table: false
            }
        }
    }
}).then(function (form) {
    $("#saveForm").on('click', function (submission) {

        var id = document.querySelector('[id^=builder-element-]').id
        var content = $(".formarea:eq(0)>div");
        var finalHtml = "";

        $.each(content, function (value, index) {
            var el = $(index);
            finalHtml += el.html();

        })
       // ajax call to save html
    });
```

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: Updated in my post

Answer (score 1):

The interface for this particular library is not documented very well in the Formio docs. The second parameter passed to `Form.builder()` is the JSON schema of the form you want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation can be found [here](https://help.form.io/developers/form-builder#formio.builder-element-form-options)

```
Formio.builder(element, [form], [options])
```

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89nczb3s/) to demo the above usage.

I am re-creating the form builder interface with JSON schema of a saved form.